# GWT Grid in ScrollPanel loses last few lines

Tags: gwt

I've got a DockLayoutPanel, in that I've got a FlowPanel, in there is an HTML (just a heading) and a ScrollPanel which contains a FlexGrid.

It all works as expected, but the ScrollPanel is too big to see in the window. It's there, but you can't see the bottom arraw (it's off the bottom of the browser). I know all the data is there: I can do a Ctrl-A, paste it into notepad and see everything, but I can't get GWT to show the whole scrollbar.

I've tried Firefow 13.0.1 and IE 9.

As an experiment, I took the HTML out of the FlowPanel (leaving just the ScrollPanel), and it all works as expected. Not sure what that actually tells me...

Any ideas how to get my scrollable FlexGrid with a non scrolling heading?

### Update

I've  found a solution, I'd appreciate comments on how good/bad/other it might be.

I've replaced the FlowPanel with a second DockLayoutPanel. My heading HTML goes into the North of the inner DockLayoutPanel and the ScrollPanel in the center of it. Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a table with a fixed header, you should consider using the DataGrid class.

Comment: I'm using FlexTable because I need "subheadings" - e.g. Main heading doesn't scroll, subheadings do. After the subheadings comes about 6 rows of data, then another subheading and so on.